# docker pull works on all machine except AWS EC2 from GitLab container registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab, registry

I cannot pull an image from a public GitLab container registry on my AWS EC2 instance, it will return a unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied.

The same image pulls without issue on my local computer (without credential) and freshly created Digital Ocean droplet with only docker installed without credentials. Doesn't work on EC2

I tried changing the WAF for linux to see if it's a firewall problem by allowing all traffic on all ports on all IPs. I have tried logging in to pull too (does not work). I have tried running with sudo and without, with new AWS instance - none of them work.

The command used to pull is

```sh
sudo docker --debug pull registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/sast:12-3-stable
```

which works everywhere else (except from within AWS EC2) which gives:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/gitlab-org/security-products/sast/manifests/12-3-stable: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied
```

Instance Information:

```
Instance type: c5d.xlarge
Region: ap-southeast-1
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Docker information:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.1
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:20:06 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.1
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Wed Aug 14 19:41:23 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `~/.docker/config.json` or `/root/.docker/config.json`? If it contains credential information, the docker engine will try to authenticate, which will then fail in your case.

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/33122 for a similar issue